# How multipe series into a dataframe with a series name per column in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a list of `pd.Series` with different date indexes and names as such:

```
trade_date
2007-01-03    0.049259
2007-01-04    0.047454
2007-01-05    0.057485
2007-01-08    0.059216
2007-01-09    0.055359
                ...   
2013-12-24    0.021048
2013-12-26    0.021671
2013-12-27    0.017898
2013-12-30    0.034071
2013-12-31    0.022301
Name: name1, Length: 1762, dtype: float64
```

I want to join this list of series into a DataFrame where each `Name` becomes a column in the DataFame and any missing indexes are set as nan.

When I try `pd.concat(list_data)` I just get one really big series instead. If i create an empty DataFrame and loop over each series in my list I get an error `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` How can I join these into a DataFame?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example for which you reproduce the error?

Comment: Maybe pd.concat(list_data, axis=1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
pd.concat(map(lambda s: s.groupby(level=0).last(), list_data), axis=1)
```

##### older answer

You should use `axis=1` in `pandas.concat`:

```
pd.concat([series1, series2, series3], axis=1)
```

example on your data (assuming s the provided series):

```
pd.concat([s, (s+1).rename('name2').iloc[5:]], axis=1)
```

output:

```
               name1     name2
trade_date                    
2007-01-03  0.049259       NaN
2007-01-04  0.047454       NaN
2007-01-05  0.057485       NaN
2007-01-08  0.059216       NaN
2007-01-09  0.055359       NaN
2013-12-24  0.021048  1.021048
2013-12-26  0.021671  1.021671
2013-12-27  0.017898  1.017898
2013-12-30  0.034071  1.034071
2013-12-31  0.022301  1.022301
```

Comment: I get the following error `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

Comment: @pyCthon how? please provide an example, this means you have a duplicate index somewhere. Also, check my update.

Comment: That update works! Sorry I should of made it more clear the indexes were different dates in each Series

Comment: @pyCthon be aware that the update drops duplicates indexes! (keeps last duplicate)

Answer (score 0):

You need to concat along the columns (combine Series horizontally):

```
pd.concat(list_data, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have multiple rows with the same date index per `Series`.

To debug this problem, you can do:

```
for sr in list_data:
    sr = sr[sr.index.value_counts() > 1]
    if len(sr):
        print(f'[sr.name]')
        print(sr, end='\n')
```

If there is an output, you can't use `concat`. Perhaps, you have to use `merge` with `how='outer'` as parameter.